# Oracle bash: export: `CLASSPATH': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, oracle

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

ORACLE_HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=orcl; export ORACLE_SID

PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH

LD_LIBRARY=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```

This code return 
**bash: export: `CLASSPATH': not a valid identifier**

I trying install oracle 11.2.0 g in oracle linux 6.0

**with bash -x return**

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ bash -x .bash_profile
+ '[' -f /home/oracle/.bashrc ']'
+ . /home/oracle/.bashrc
++ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
++ . /etc/bashrc
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ shopt -q login_shell
+++ '[' 500 -gt 199 ']'
++++ /usr/bin/id -gn
++++ /usr/bin/id -un
+++ '[' oracle = oracle ']'
+++ umask 002
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/cvs.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/cvs.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/glib2.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/glib2.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/lang.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/less.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/less.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/qt.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/qt.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vim.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/vim.sh
+++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
+++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/which2.sh ']'
+++ '[' '' ']'
+++ . /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
+++ unset i
+++ unset pathmunge
+ PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin
+ export PATH
+ ORACLE_HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
+ export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
+ ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl
+ export ORACLE_UNQNAME
+ ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
+ export ORACLE_BASE
+ ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
+ export ORACLE_HOME
+ ORACLE_SID=orcl
+ export ORACLE_SID
+ PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/bin
+ export PATH
+ LD_LIBRARY=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
+ export LD_LIBRARY
+ CLASSPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/jlib:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/rdbms/jlib
+ export $'CLASSPATH\357\273\277'
.bash_profile: line 22: export: `CLASSPATH': not a valid identifier
```

The bash -x in terminal return this code above, in the line 22, i use oracle linux 6.0 and oracle 11.2.0g details details details details details details details details details details details details details details

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x yourscript` so it'll print the command as they're executed, and [edit] the results into the question. Likely there's a hidden character next to `CLASSPATH`, so it's actually trying to export something like `CLASSPATH$'\r'`

Comment: BTW, snippet support is for code that can be run inside a web browser -- use the `{}` button in the editor to syntax-highlight other languages.

Comment: (...and as another aside, a given variable only needs to be exported once -- future changes will be copied to the environment automatically -- and `PATH` is, in the case of your shell init scripts, going to be *already* exported before your shell is ever started; `export`ing it over and over is needless).

Comment: I used {} but not work

Comment: The code needs to be selected before clicking `{}`.

Comment: thanks mann for a answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of your `set -x` output:

```
+ export $'CLASSPATH\357\273\277'
```

It appears that for whichever reason, you have an invisible unicode byte order mark at the end of your file.

Use a different editor that will show such characters and/or let you delete it. For example, in Vim it will show up as a blue `<feff>` that can be deleted like any other character.

If you don't have a good editor available, you can delete it with GNU sed from Bash:

```
sed -i $'s/\357\273\277//g' yourfile
```